# Zsh Script to execute command on files sorted by size in a directory

Tags: bash

I have to run some commands on all files in a directory starting **from the smallest file in size to the largest file**. The script is running fine with **'ls'** command and its sorting ability but certain posts mentioned to avoid using 'ls' in case there are filenames with spaces. Please guide me about any alternative way for this?

Thanks

```
for file in `ls -Sr directory/*.txt`; do
....commands....
done
```

Answer (score 3):

Read your output line by line and use `-1`:

```
while IFS= read -r file; do
    ...
done < <(exec ls -1 -Sr directory/*.txt)
```

Another:

```
readarray -t files < <(exec ls -1 -Sr directory/*.txt)
for file in "${files[@]}"; do
    ...
done
```

That is, if you're really using `bash`.

For `Zsh`:`

```
while IFS= read -u 4 -r file; do
    echo "$file"
done 4< =(exec ls -1 -Sr directory/*.txt)
```

Comment: If not `bash`, OP could try `ls ... | while read ... do ... done` Just that it will be in sub-shell.

Comment: Thanks! I edited to include my exact shell to be zsh.

Answer (score 0):

using **find** would be a better option. Assign the output of find command to a array and iterate through the array as below.(This will handle if there are spaces in the filename)

```
 OLDIFS=$IFS
 IFS=$'\n'
 files=$(find directory -type f -name \*.txt -exec du {} \; |sort -n | cut -d$'\t' -f2-);
 for file in ${files}; do
  ....commands....
 done
 IFS=$OLDIFS
```

If you want to search non recursively add **-maxdepth 1**

```
 OLDIFS=$IFS
 IFS=$'\n'
 files=$(find directory -type f -maxdepth 1 -name \*.txt -exec du {} \; |sort -n | cut -d$'\t' -f2-);
 for file in ${files}; do
  ....commands....
 done
 IFS=$OLDIFS
```

Comment: How to remove recursive find from this command? Right now its finding all files within subdirectories in current directory as well?

Comment: @CSamuel add -maxdepth 1. like     files=$(find directory -maxdepth 1 -type f -name \*.txt -exec du {} \; |sort -n | cut -d$'\t' -f2-);

Comment: This will NOT handle files with spaces!! Iteration in `for` will be broken by any files with space or other some strange symbols!

Comment: @rush : why do you think that it does not handle space?

Comment: @grep_code: because try this out: `mkdir /tmp/1 ; cd /tmp/1 ; touch test "new test" "very test" ; t=$(find . -name "*test") ; for i in $t ; do echo $i ; done`

Comment: @rush: got it!! Thanks :) Need to set the IFS in order to handle space

Comment: @grep code: But this is executing commands on only the last file in the list i.e. the largest file.

Comment: @C Samuel . I have re-checked it again. It is retrieving all the file names present in that directory based on the file sizes(ascending). Can you check at your end!!

Comment: @grepcode : Shouldn't maxdepth come before -type f ?
I am getting an error :
find: warning: you have specified the -maxdepth option after a non-option argument -type

Answer (score 0):

try this out :-

```
for file in `find directory/ -iname "*.txt" -type f  | xargs du | sort -n | awk '{print $2}'`; do
    ....commands....
done
```

Comment: This does not work as expected as du -h gives the size in human readable format along with the metric(M,K,B). So numeric sort on that would give you improper results. Sample output for your command    `find directory/ -type f  | xargs du -h | sort -n `                     **608K ./Softwares/Ciscodd-On.dmg
712K ./Softwares/coreutils-7.4/doc/coreutils.info
780M ./business-analytx64.app/Contents/MacOS/installbuilder
785M ./pentaho-business-analytics-5.0.5-x64.app.tar.gz
788K ./Softwares/commons-logging-1.1.3-bin.zip
928K ./Personal/statem787ent.pdf
932K ./mysql-connector-j0-bin.jar**

Comment: No, It wont. I am saying that sorting will not happen correctly. suppose you have files with size 608K, 785 M, 677K, 928K. Your output would return files in the following order 608K,677K, 785M, 928K which is not correct. use du instead of du -h.

Comment: Sorry. Even this does not work.:) You need to change the default delimiter of AWK to handle output of du.(Make sure you handle spaces in the filename)

Comment: Please never again use `for i in \`find\`` construction. Any file with space or strange sybol will break the cycle. Use `for i in *` or `find | while read` cycle.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you're quoting everything, I can't think of a problem with iterating over an output of `ls -Sr` that has file names with spaces.

When using command substitution, and whenever you reference the variable `"$file"` inside the loop, you should use double quotes.

```
for file in "$(ls -Sr directory/*.txt)"; do
    ....commands....
done
```

But if you want to avoid `ls`, you could do something like this:

```
while read -r _ file; do
    ....commands....
done < <(du directory/*.txt|sort -n)
```

Comment: Thanks John B. But I am not sure how will this operate on files from smallest to largest in size?

Comment: Totally missed that.  No biggie, only a major part of the question :)  Please see my rewritten post.

Answer (score 0):

```
sh$ xargs -d '\n' -L1 echo < <(ls -Sr directory/*.txt)
directory/a.txt
directory/a b.txt
```

Of course, replace `echo` by your actual command.

Comment: Thanks Sylvian Leroux. But I am afraid there are multiple commands to be run inside the for loop along with some if statements too. This implementation would become difficult in that case.